# How can I connect to wi-fi using Ubuntu (17.04) within Oracle VM VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, wireless, virtualbox, oracle

I have Ubuntu (17.04) running in a virtual machine (Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.1.22) installed on my Windows 10 laptop. I can connect via ethernet cable, but I cannot even see any available wireless network around me. Has anyone found a good solution for it?
I know a similar question has been already asked ([How do I connect to the wifi in Ubuntu within my Virtual Machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379438/how-do-i-connect-to-the-wifi-in-ubuntu-within-my-virtual-machine)), but no one resolved the problem.

EDIT: really don't know why, but after a week using ethernet cable, now I can normally connect to wi-fi. I only enabled NAT configuration on network settings of the virtual machine. No Broadcom wireless driver needed.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a USB wifi card you can pass through to the VM, you can't.

The host wifi device is never exposed to the VM as a wifi device.  You need to directly pass a USB wifi adapter to the VM for it to accept wireless.  There's no other way to do this with current virtualization systems built on top of an existing OS.

This is detailed in my answer to [Wireless card isnt working with Ubuntu 14.04 VirtualBox Guest OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529408/wireless-card-isnt-working-with-ubuntu-14-04-virtualbox-guest-os/529488#529488), including the network diagram there, and the full explanation of how the virtual networking works in VirtualBox.

Comment: I thought it depended on the fact that i can't visualize Broadcom Wireless Drivers in the wi-fi settings. But anyway, thank you for your time.

Comment: @Giuliano Nope, it's usually because host network devices are not exposed to the guest as those devices, which the diagram in the linked answer indicates.  You'd need a separate adapter unfortunately - one you can pass through USB to the VM.  You're welcome though!  (I had the same problem... now I just have a 4port portable usb hub with 4 wifi adapters in it for my VMs wherever I go heh...)

Comment: In my case vmware player12 was working with wifi perfectly fine for like two days after setup. But suddenly it stopped working today! I didn't touch any settings! It was working on bridge mode with replicating physical status of the connection checked.